# htaccess not working as it should

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

well, ofcourse its not working, im still a n00b :)

this is the code that i have :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.css - [S=7]
RewriteRule (.*)\.jpg - [S=6]
RewriteRule ^gallery gallery.html [L]

RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ index.html?page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.html?page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/ index.html?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.html?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, this works fine, if i try localhost/abc 
but it wont work if i try localhost/abc/

also, when i try localhost/abc/def (or localhost/abc/def/ for that matter) the css file isnt being included properly. i get an error saying /abc/def/style.css does not exist. :(

however, the code doesnt work if i remove the QSA flag from the last rule. this is the code that ive come up with after a lot of googling and reading SO. if anyone can help out i'll be extremely grateful.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sort your trailing slash issue with 
(/)? rather than / alone

?=zero or one of the preceding char

Comment: did you do 
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)(/)?$ index.html?page=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

You should use more specific patterns. `.*` means zero or more arbitrary characters. That matches anything, even the empty string.

In your case `abc/` is probably matched by the rule with the pattern `(.*)/(.*)` and not the rule with `(.*)/` as you might have assumed.

Try `[^/]+` instead (one or more characters except the `/`) and add assertions for the start (`^`) and end of the string (`$`):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.html?page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.html?page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.html?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.html?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And as shaunhare.co.uk already said, you can set the trailing `/` optional by appending the `?` quantifier to it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.html?page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.html?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: hey gumbo. i tried the rules you suggested. unfortunately, no matter what url i try, its getting redirected to index.html. 
any advice? thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: hey gumbo. after a little tweaking, i got these rules working: 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/)?$ index.html?page=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/)?$ index.html?page=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)?$ index.html?page=home [L,QSA] 

but the css file is also getting rewritten (eg: /abc/styles.css) any suggestsions?

Comment: @hsn: You don’t need to put the single `/` in a group like `(/)`; `/?` works too. And you could use a rule that stops the rewrite process if the request can be mapped to an existing file: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f RewriteRule ^ - [L]` Put this rule in front of your others and it should work. Then you even don’t need the first two rules.

Comment: hey gumbo. i tried the new rule. now its causing an internal server error :S

Comment: @hsn: You need to write each directive in its own line.

Comment: hey gumbo. i did infact place the lines correctly. but its still not working. i have an echo 'this page is '.$_GET['page'] in my index.html file and the css files that are being included in each page contain "this page is style.css" :S

also, can i ask how you're using the code tags in the comments? i cant find it here :P havent ever asked on SO before :D

Comment: @hsn: Did you place the rule in front of the others?